# How to set paths for template files in one config like file in requireJs so that I do not have to pass template path url to my module?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, single-page-application

Considering the folder structure below.

```
app/js/config.js
app/js/views/home/a.js
app/js/views/search/b.js

app/tmp/home/a.htm
app/tmp/search/b.htm
```

In my require.config (in js/config.js), I can do the following for the js files:

```
 paths: {

          Vhome_a: 'views/home/a',
          Vsearch_b: 'views/search/b'

 },
```

however, I cannot do the follwing for the template (.htm) files  :

```
paths: {

          Thome_a: 'text!../tmp/home/a.htm',
          Tsearch_b: 'text!../tmp/search/b.htm'

},
```

I would like to list all my templates in a file so that I can manage them from one place and refer to them in the application using the alias (names for template path urls) created in this file. Is this possible using requireJs or any other way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, just use the `text!` plugin in the require function, so in your config file write this:

```
paths: {

          Thome_a: '../tmp/home/a.htm',
          Tsearch_b: '../tmp/search/b.htm'

},
```

and require the templates like this:

```
require(['text!Thome_a'], function(thome_a){...});
```